# Qt network request auto adding unexpected question mark

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I am trying to send http POST request. Here is code snippets:

```
    const QUrl URL("https://httpbin.org/post");
    QNetworkRequest req(URL);
    req.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    QUrlQuery urlQuery;
    urlQuery.addQueryItem ("username", username);
    urlQuery.addQueryItem ("password", password);
    QUrl params;
    params.setQuery (urlQuery);


    mNetReply = mNetMan->post(req, params.toEncoded());
```

and here is the response output:

```
QJsonObject({"args":{},"data":"","files":{},"form":{"?username":"xyz","password":"xyz"},"headers":{"Accept-Encoding":"gzip, deflate","Accept-Language":"en-US,*","Connection":"close","Content-Length":"28","Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded","Host":"httpbin.org","User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"},"json":null,"origin":"*.*.*.*","url":"https://httpbin.org/post"})
```

My problem is , qt automatically adding a `?` mark in first queryItem.

Comment: But queries are followed by a question mark, no?
E.g. www.xyz.com?GetName,GetID.
And since it is added to the 1st item, I believe it is by design

Can you write how your URI is supposed to look after adding the query items?

Comment: you are right . Its not the best way to send http form data. any idea how to do it ?

Comment: First thing is, why are you posting a query. Are you not supposed to use get instead of post?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For what it's worth still, because an answer was not given:

Don't use the conversion to a QUrl, using the QUrlQuery directly solved the problem for me.

```
urlQuery.toString(QUrl::FullyEncoded).toUtf8()
```

in stead of

```
params.toEncoded()
```

Total snippet updated:

```
const QUrl URL("https://httpbin.org/post");
QNetworkRequest req(URL);
req.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

QUrlQuery urlQuery;
urlQuery.addQueryItem ("username", username);
urlQuery.addQueryItem ("password", password);

mNetReply = mNetMan->post(req, urlQuery.toString(QUrl::FullyEncoded).toUtf8());
```